# Is there a pattern or library for a "record with types as keys"?

Tags: haskell

Is there an ergonomic solution to combine multiple records where fields partially overlap, for both defining the types and then operating on the values?

A contrived example, having data types `A { int :: Int, double :: Double }` and `B { string :: String, unit :: () }` is there a way to (morally) get a data type `C { int :: Int, double :: Double, string :: String }` which combines the former two values. For my case, the type uniquely determines the field, i.e, there are no two fields with the same type (though even if there were, I guess a `newtype` could help).

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Data Types a la Carte](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/14416CB20C4637164EA9F77097909409/S0956796808006758a.pdf/data_types_a_la_carte.pdf).  If it's just for ergonomics it's probably more trouble than it's worth.  But if you have a design problem where this shows up in some essential way, it's worth looking into.

Comment: Does `(A, B)` do what you need? If not, why not?

Comment: @DanielWagner It has the fields overlapping fields twice.